# Unable to change Minimum & Maximum on Excel chart axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

Sometimes when I'm making a graph in Excel, the program won't let me change the minimum or maximum on the axis.

If I try to change the number, then the entire number disappears and I can't input a new number.

This doesn't happen on all graphs, just some.

I can often delete the existing number or delete the right-hand digits, but then I can't replace them with the digits that I want -- the system simply won't accept the numbers.

The numbers that are there start to become wavy, appearing and disappearing -- it's very strange.

I'm attaching a snip to show that yes I do know what I'm doing, I've been making Excel graphs for about 25 years. This is the first time I've ever seen this. It's clearly a bug in the latest version of Excel.

Is there any way to get around it?

[image]

Comment: On which types of charts exactly did you see this issue?

Comment: Simple line graphs. Nothing fancy. Come to think of it, I believe they're all graphs with two lines graphed on separate axes, and it's the right-hand axis that gives me problems. I think -- I never considered whether there was a pattern before.

Comment: Sounds like something is screwy with Excel. What version are you running? I suspect you may need to perform a "repair install".